# Replacing conversation function. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, authentication, security, pam, sshd

The application (in my case, the sshd) supplies the conversation function. Is it possible to replace the conversation function in a custom PAM module? I tried to do this but does not work. It appears that PAM is stuck with the conversation function provided in the application.
How do I use an alternate conversation function, preferably in the PAM, and not use the application's conversation function?